# Trying to retrieve the environment variable returns null

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I have set a variable to the user with the below command.

`c:\>set something="C:\programfiles\win\something"`

When I try to get the variable using `System.Environment.GetVariable("something")`, I get the value as null.

Please can anyone explain the problem on this?

Comment: Are you running the program in the same console? Environment variables are not propagated between console sessions (assuming Windows because of 'programfiles').

Answer (score 2):

If you set environment variable using the `set` command, that variable is actually set only in the current console. So, if you have application that prints out the variable `something` called `var.exe`, it works fine:

```
C:\>var.exe


C:\>set something=x

C:\>var.exe
x
```

But if you run the same application from another console (or without one), the variable won't be set.

It seems you can't set environment variable globally using the `set` command. But you can do it from .Net application using [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) (by specifying the `target` parameter) or manually from Windows in the “Environment variables” window.

Answer (score 1):

set command sets the variable only in console scope. Instead of doing this you can set this variable in system properties.